# How to reset state in children class component at the same time with parent component in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-state-management

I'm a newbie in React Native and struggling in cleaning up the state of the children component at the same time with the parent.

What I'm trying to do is:

1. After navigating from `MainMap.js` to the last screen `TripsListScreen.js` (the whole process is a Stack of 4 screens, nested in a Drawer), I got all the data stored in Redux's store, and display it in `TripsListScreen`.
2. I then press the `add` button to create new trips. I successfully reset the state at the `MainMap`. However, the states ( `value` prop of `TextInput`) in the `PlaceInput` component is still there. How can we reset that also ?

Here's the **`MainMap.js`** 's states:

```
const initialState = {
    hasMapPermission: false,
    _userLocationDisplayed: null,
    userLatitude: 0,
    userLongitude: 0,
    initial_UserLatitude: 0,
    initial_UserLongitude: 0,
    userLocationAddress: '',

    destination: [],
    destinationName: [],
    destinationAddress: [],
    destinationCoords: [],
    destinationImageUri: [],

    numOfInput:[0,1],
    counter: 1,
    wayPoints: [],
    markers: [],

    doCleanState: 'no' // Right here I want to pass the prop from PlaceInput as this.state.doCleanState
};
const cleanUpState = {
    hasMapPermission: false,

    destination: [],
    destinationName: [],
    destinationAddress: [],
    destinationCoords: [],
    destinationImageUri: [],

    numOfInput:[0,1],
    counter: 1,
    wayPoints: [],
    markers: [],

    doCleanState: 'yes'
}

class MainMap extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = initialState;
    };


    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('Hello',this.props);
        console.log('This is state', this.state);
        this._requestUserLocation();
        this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
            this.setState(cleanUpState);

        })
    };

    componentWillUnmount(){
        Geolocation.clearWatch(this.watch_location_id);
        this._unsubscribe();

    }

   render(){
      return(
        //...
        <PlaceInput
            id={itemData}

            defaultValue={this.state._userLocationDisplayed}
            displayDefaultValue={!index}
            doCleanState={this.state.doCleanState}
       />
  );
}
```

Basically, I've tried to pass a prop from the `PlaceInput` as a state in `MainMap`. When resetting the `MainMap`'s states( the state of `doCleanState` also changes, not reset), the states of `PlaceInput` doesn't reset

Here's **`PlaceInput`**:

```
//...
class PlaceInput extends React.Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            predictions: [],
            destinationInput: '',
        }
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
        if(this.props.doCleanState !== prevProps.doCleanState){
            this.setState({
                destinationInput: '',
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <TextInput 
                key={this.id}

                placeholder='Search your places'

                onChangeText={(input) => {
                    this.setState({destinationInput: input});
                    this.getPlacesDebounced(input);
                }}
                value={this.props.displayDefaultValue ? this.props.defaultValue : this.state.destinationInput} // props.defaultValue is state of MainMap : 'Your location'
                             // destinationInput is what the users type

             />
   );
}
//...
```

When I navigate back to `MainMap` the `destinationInput` state is still there in the `PlaceInput`

[image: Problem]

**PLEASE HELP !!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PlaceInput component, pass props value to parent where you want,

```
class PlaceInput extends React.Component{

    //... your code method
    this.props.updateClean("") // pass your value to parent

}
```

Then in MainMap component,

```
<PlaceInput
        id={itemData}

        defaultValue={this.state._userLocationDisplayed}
        displayDefaultValue={!index}
        doCleanState={this.state.doCleanState}
        updateClean={(text)=> setState({doCleanState:text})} // <-- change like this. 
   />
```

Answer (score 1):

See if this helps:

```
class MainMap extends React.Component{
  // ...
    componentDidMount(){
        // ...
        this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
          // destructure the cleanUpState so you aren't passing a global reference around
          this.setState({...cleanUpState});
        });
    };
    // ...
```

When you just assign the state to `cleanUpState`, you now have a reference to that global object and are modifying it throughout your app. You need to make sure to destructure objects so that you are passing copies of them, and not their references.